# How to format an instant in a particular locale at a particular timezone for a human

Tags: java, java-8, datetime-format

I am using:

```java
Locale locale = Locale.FRENCH;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(locale).withZone(zone);
System.out.println(formatter.format(Instant.now()));
```

The result I get is `lundi 25 mai 2020 20 h 21 CEST` with `Locale.FRENCH` and `Monday, May 25, 2020 8:05:11 PM CEST` with `Locale.English`

I found the `CEST` to not be user friendly for non IT people, how can I reliably remove it?

**Edit**

I do not want to have `CLDR` enabled, my users already know in which country they are, so we can safely remove the time zone information.

I must be able to deal with AN/PM and 24 hours format, without listing all the countries.

How is that possible?

Comment: I get `lundi 25 mai 2020 à 21:01:17 heure d’été d’Europe centrale`. So no funny zone abbreviation. With English locale I get `Monday, May 25, 2020 at 9:02:41 PM Central European Summer Time`. Using Java 11.

Comment: I use java 8, but thanks for this it's interesting to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Exploit CLDR

I understand that you are using Java 8, and on my Java 8 I can reproduce your results. To avoid the user-unfriendly abbreviation `CEST` (and similar for other time zones), I suggest that you use CLDR, Unicode Common Locale Data Repository.

Either run your Java program with this JVM argument: `-Djava.locale.providers=CLDR`.

Or set the system property from within your program:

```
    System.setProperty("java.locale.providers", "CLDR");
```

This changes your output. Now using French locale the output is:

> lundi 25 mai 2020 21:06:07 heure avancée d’Europe centrale

And in English:

> Monday, May 25, 2020 9:09:39 PM Central European Summer Time

How come it works? Java gets its locale data, including the date and time formats used in different locales, from up to four sources. In versions up to and including Java 8, Java’s own locale data are the default; but the default is changed through the system property mentioned. In Java 9 and later, CLDR is the default ([JEP 252](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252)). So making this change to use CLDR in Java 8 will also prepare you for migrating to Java 9 or later.

### To leave out time zone completely

> I want to remove the time zone since the user already know that he is
>   [in h]is country.

Side note in passing: In some cases users like to be assured that they are getting the time in their own time zone. It will also help disambiguate in case you need to print a time in the fall overlap where clocks are turned back. `heure avancée d’Europe centrale` will be printed before the clock change and `heure normale de l’Europe centrale` after it.

Of course you know better what *your* users want and need. So there are a couple of options:

1. Manually take out the time zone from the format pattern as demonstrated in the answer by munge.
2. Use `FormatStyle.MEDIUM`. This was already suggested in a now deleted answer by Deadpool. You may use different format styles for date and for time:

   ```
       DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
               .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL, FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
               .withLocale(locale)
               .withZone(zone);
       System.out.println(formatter.format(Instant.now()));
   ```

   Examle output in French locale on Java 8:

   > mardi 26 mai 2020 19:26:59

   And in English locale:

   > Tuesday, May 26, 2020 7:27:26 PM

Comment: "heure avancée d’Europe centrale" and "Central European Summer Time" is simply the long version of CEST

Comment: I want to remove the time zone since the user already know that he is is country.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa So use another `DateTimeFormatter` to generate text in any format you want. This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not really. Because you can't have one formatter that handle 24H format and AM/PM format depending on locale. The one way I have found is to format the same time twice, for date and then for time. This seems to not be coverable by one formatter, on stackoverflow or anywhere else

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I understand. I have added a couple of options in the answer.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know we can use a different formatter for hours, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To reliably remove time zone information you first have to get the locale-specific pattern and adapt it before you use it for formatting:

```
Locale locale = Locale.FRENCH;
Instant instant = Instant.now();

String pattern = getPatternWithoutTimezone(FormatStyle.FULL, Chronology.from(instant), locale);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withLocale(locale)
    .withZone(TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId());
System.out.println(formatter.format(Instant.now()));

...

 private String getPatternWithoutTimezone(FormatStyle style, Chronology chronology,
  Locale locale) {
String pattern = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder
    .getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.FULL, FormatStyle.FULL, chronology, locale);

/* remove time zone from pattern 
 * (see spec of "Date and time pattern" in Javadoc of java.text.SimpleDateFormat class)
 */
return pattern.replaceAll("[zZX]", "");
```

}

Note that *.withLocale(locale)* is still required, otherwise you would only use the locale-specific format but not localized names of days, months, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can customise what you want to show and what not
e.g `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a")`
gives `lundi, mai 25, 2020 07:02:57 PM`

Comment: With this you get a format without a timezone but the format will always be the same, independent from the locale. But every locale has its specific format: e.g. in France the 24 hour clock is used, while in other countries the 12 hour clock is used with AM and PM.

Comment: Is the `A` for PM? because in `Locale.FRENCH`, we do not need it, how can we anticipate that? @rmunge this is what I want, because the user in france does not need to know that the time he's for it's time zone. I have removed the accepted answer since this doesn't deal with 24 hour clock

Comment: While I try to test it with my date it gives me an error: `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfWeek`

Comment: _UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfWeek_ is thrown when you try to format an instance of TemporalAccessor that does not contain information about a date. For example. an instance of LocalTime only contains a time but not an explicit date.. Only instances that contain both, time and date can be formatted with a date + time pattern.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa yes the `a` at the end is for AM/PM, for 24h format you can get rid of it and change `hh` to `HH`

Comment: Yes, but then the US user that does not use the 24 hours format will not get a localized string for his country, how can I deal with that without having to list all the countries in the world?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Locale can't be deduced from timezone, so for locale specific things, there is no alternative. The only improvement you can do is get rid of zone and use `LocalDateTime.now()` instead of `Instant.now()`

Comment: Is use Instant in our Java object and timestamp and timestamptz SQL data type, we do not want to change that. But this is just for formatting, I feel like it is ok to convert from `Instant` to `LocaleDateTime` just for that task, do you have an idea on how to do that? And how will it removed the zoned information from the formatted date? Those date are specific per user's time zone, a user in NYC will have it's expiring date time at midnight  NYC, while a user in paris will have he's expiring date time at midnight Paris.